# Sybase SQL - null condition, removing whitespace

Tags: sql, sybase

I've got this query below that drove me mad, would you be able to fix the code below so that the result will be like this : "123 Bridge St 2500" instead of " 123 Bridge St  2500" (extra whitespace at the beginning and in between St and 2500)?

```
declare @street varchar(20), @street2 varchar(20), @suburb varchar(20), @postcode varchar(4)
set @street = null
set @street2 = '123 Bridge St'
set @suburb = null
set @postcode = '2500'

select address = case @street when null then '' else @street + ' ' end
                        +case @street2 when null then '' else @street2 + ' ' end
                        +case @suburb when null then '' else @suburb + ' ' end
                        +case @postcode when null then '' else @postcode + ' ' end

-- Expected Result: '123 Bridge St 2500'
-- Actual Result: ' 123 Bridge St  2500'
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `case @street when null then` to `case when @street is null then` and the others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments,

here's the solution that worked

```
select address = ltrim(rtrim(@street) + ' ') + ltrim(rtrim(@street2) + ' ') + ltrim(rtrim(@suburb) + ' ') + @postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select case when @street is null then '' else @street + ' ' end
                        +case when @street2 is null then '' else @street2 + ' ' end
                        +case when @suburb is null then '' else @suburb + ' ' end
                        +case when @postcode is null then '' else @postcode + ' ' end
```

When you write `case @street when null..` that's the same as `when @street = null` which doesn't work, so use `is null` instead.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that, I've tried but the same result " 123 Bridge St  2500" there are whitespace.

Comment: @insignificant Can you try above with `select case when @street is null then 'x' else @street + 'y' end` and see what you get?